# Stuck in infinite loop when use while with continue

Tags: javascript

I wrote a code to loop through an array and when I used while and the continue statement inside it I got stuck in infinite loop:

```
function loop(){
    var x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
    var i = 0;
    while ( i < x.length){
         if (x[i] % 2 == 0){
               continue;
         }
         i++
    }
    console.log(x[i])
}
loop()
```

I tried to add the `i++` outside the loop and inside it I got the same result.

The expected result is 1,3,5,....etc the actual result is infinite loop.

Comment: Well if the `if` test is *true*, what happens to `i`? Because the test relies on the values of `x` and `i`, if they don't change the `if` test will remain the same. The `continue` statement breaks out of the body of the loop and goes back to the top.

Comment: As @pointy mentioned above you need to change i in if also so add I++ in if to fix it

Comment: If you really want to learn programming, you should figure this out on your own instead of getting answers here. Debugging skill is the key to understanding code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`continue` goes immediately to the next iteration of the loop, skipping the rest of the loop body. So it skips over the `i++`, and the next iteration tests the same `x[i]`. Since nothing has changed, the condition succeeds again, so it keeps doing the same thing.

You just want to skip over the `console.log(x[i])` statement, not everything in the body.

Also, you didn't put the `console.log(x[i])` inside the loop at all, so even if the loop worked correctly you wouldn't have printed out the odd elements; it would just print `x[i]` after the loop is done, and since `i` then would be outside the array, it would print `undefined.

```js
function loop() {
  var x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
  var i = 0;
  while (i < x.length) {
    if (x[i] % 2 != 0) {
      console.log(x[i]);
    }
    i++
  }
}
loop()
```

If you really want to use `while` and `continue`, you can put `i++` before the test. But then you have to subtract `1` from `i` when using it as the array index.

```js
function loop() {
  var x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
  var i = 0;
  while (i < x.length) {
    i++;
    if (x[i - 1] % 2 == 0) {
      continue;
    }
    console.log(x[i - 1]);
  }
}
loop()
```

You could also use a `for` loop instead of `while`, since the `i++` will be in the `for()` header, which is executed every time.

```js
function loop() {
  var x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (x[i] % 2 == 0) {
      continue;
    }
    console.log(x[i])
  }
}
loop()
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that `i` should increment whether or not the condition is true or not, otherwise it'll continue to test the same value over and over again indefinitely.

```js
function loop(){
    const x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
    for(let i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
         if (x[i] % 2 == 0){
               continue;
         }
         console.log(x[i])
    }
}
loop()
```

Modern JS:

```js
function loop(){
    const x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
    return x.filter(n=>n % 2 !== 0);
}
const res = loop();
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to print out the odd numbers in the loop, try just printing them:

```js
function loop() {
    var x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
    var i = 0;
    while ( i < x.length){
         if (x[i] % 2 == 1){
               console.log(x[i]);
         }
         i++;
    }
    
}
loop()
```

What’s happening right now is that your loop is not increasing `i`, so when the number is even you `continue` right past `i++` and never get past that number, leading to an infinite loop. This way, whether the number is odd or even you increment i.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you do not increase `i` in the condition.

Use this:

```
function loop(){
    var x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
    var i = 0;
    while ( i < x.length){
        if (x[i++] % 2 == 0){
           continue;
        }
        console.log(i);
    }
    console.log(x[i])
}

loop()
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want to iterate through an array, use `for` loop

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: What's the problem with while loop?

Comment: the ```.forEach()``` function is made for this case

Comment: `.forEach()` is not a for loop.

Comment: Yes it's a function as I mentioned but it's pretty much the same use that a for loop when it comes to array.